# Geoserver with OpenLayers WMS Images are only shown on localhost pc

Tags: openlayers, layer, geoserver, wms

i have a problem with wms from GeoServer on my OpenLayers-page.
On the localhost, where Geoserver and the webpage is running, i can see both the wms and the wfs. If i run the page on another device (other computer, laptop, ipad), the wms isn´t shown but the wfs works fine. So there shouldn´t be a mistake on the webpage.
There are also no problems reported in geoserver.

i also tried different wms but the problem is always the same:
shown on the localhost-pc but not on other devices.
(also tried it on localhost with his IP instead of localhost --> works also fine!)

Answer (score 0):

there could be several problems connected with this issue. It would be great if you could do some tests to provide more information about the problem. Mabye you did some of them, or you already know the answers, but...

1. check the network traffic in your browser (F12, network traffic in IE, firebug in FF...), if the browser hits the service. If there is an answer, and the wms doesn't return raster, but some text, you can read this text in the response body, it's probably an error. Or you can copy the particular request URL and run it in a separate browser window. That would be the same. If there is no error, the problem is probably that you cannot reach the map server.
2. check the firewall on the map server. It is probable, that your map server doesn't run on the "usual" port, so there is a great chance that your outgoing communication for the non-standard port is prohibited on the local (server-local) firewall. (true story :))
3. there might be a cross-domain request problem, but I give it no so many chances when your wfs (POST) request is working, while wms (GET) returns a problem. Usually it is vice versa, the POST is more dangerous and more "cross-domain sensitive".

maybe some more potential problems cross my mind, so I will add them here, but so far, I don't know. It would be great if you (e.g.) used [fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler) or some other network-traffic-debbugging oriented tool and have a closer look at the requests and answers from the server.

Comment: At the webpage the url for both the wms and the wfs is http:// localhost:8080/...but only the wfs use the proxy.cgi-File. So i changed the url of the wms to http:// IP-adress:8080/... now it works on all the other devices! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm glad you found the problem, although this wasn't any of my guesses :)